# Accessing module defined operation such as: type 'a zipper = LZ of 'a list * 'a list

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

Let's suppose we have a module defined like this:

```
module type LIST_ZIPPER = 
  sig
    type 'a zipper
    exception First
    exception Last
    exception Empty
    val empty : 'a zipper
    (* returns the sublist starting at focus position*)
    val get : 'a zipper -> 'a list
    (* add/remove under focus operation *)
    val insert : 'a zipper -> 'a -> 'a zipper
    val remove : 'a zipper -> 'a zipper option
    val remove_exn : 'a zipper -> 'a zipper 
    (* focus-moving operation *)
    val previous : 'a zipper -> 'a zipper 
    val next : 'a zipper -> 'a zipper 
end

module ListZipper2 : LIST_ZIPPER = 
  struct
    type 'a zipper = LZ of 'a list * 'a list
    exception First
    exception Last
    exception Empty
    let empty : 'a zipper = LZ ([],[])
    let get (LZ (_,l) : 'a zipper) : 'a list = l
    let insert (LZ (l, r)) a = LZ (l,a::r)
    let remove lz = 
      match lz with
    | LZ (l, h::t) -> Some (LZ (l,t))
    | LZ (_,[]) -> None
    let remove_exn (lz : 'a zipper) : 'a zipper = 
      match remove lz with
      | Some lz -> lz
      | None -> raise Empty
    let previous lz =
       match lz with
    | LZ (h::t, l) -> LZ (t, h::l)
    | LZ ([],_) -> raise First
    let next lz = 
      match lz with
    | LZ (l, h::t) -> LZ (h::l,t)
    | LZ (_,[]) -> raise Last
  end
```

and I want to to create a zipper like this:

```
open ListZipper2
let (zip : ListZipper2.zipper) =  LZ ([1;2;3], [4;5])
```

and it doesn't work, what is the proper way? I can access operations defined such as `ListZipper2.insert`, but if I can't create a zipper, then what is the benefit of module in this case?

Comment: Please provide details on the `LIST_ZIPPER` module type.

Comment: I did above a moment ago

Comment: Good. This confirms octachron's answer. The `'a zipper` type is abstract. functions to transform to and from `'a list` would be good things to add to the module. E.g. `let to_list (LZ (l, r)) = List.rev l @ r`

Comment: Would `let from_list_to_zipper l = (LZ([], l))` be correct if we consider the the focus is at front of the list?

Comment: Yes. However, if it's in the `ListZipper2` module, you can probably just call it `from_list`. And you can skip the extraneous parens. `let from_list lst = LZ ([], lst)`

Comment: And for the opposite, what is usually conceived, let's say we have this zipper `LZ ([1;2;3], [4;5;6])` we know that the substructure `[4;5;6]` is always in order, but the context is in reverse, but what does mean to convert the zipper to list? We got something like `[3;2;1;4;5;6]` Why?

Comment: So this `let to_list (LZ(c, s)) = List.rev c @ s;; `? but what is the point, how can we know the focus if we want to get this list to zipper again?

Comment: The "context" in a list zipper data structure is in reverse because consing onto a list is a cheap (_O(1)_) operation, while appending at the end (_O(n)_)is expensive. So `let to_list (LZ (left, right)) = List.rev left @ right`  The answer to "how do you know the focus" is that you do everything that benefits from the zipper's efficiency _before_ converting back to a list.

Comment: Yes, I didn't ask why we reverse the context, I meant why we do this configuration `[3;2;1;4;5;6]`

Comment: Which scenario we might use that list from zipper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your module type `LIST_ZIPPER` most probably defines `'a zipper` as an abstract type:

```ml
module type LIST_ZIPPER = sig
  type 'a zipper
  ...
end
```

Once you have restricted an implementation to this module type with

```ml
module ListZipper2 : LIST_ZIPPER = struct
  ...
end
```

you can no longer peek inside the implementation detail of the module.
This is by design since it enforces that the rest of the code will work with any `LIST_ZIPPER` independently of its contingent implementation.

Note that this requires the `LIST_ZIPPER` module type to support enough operations for subsequent users to use the `zipper`. If you defined the `LIST_ZIPPER` module type yourself, it may happen that the module resulting
from the signature constraint is unusable. For instance, with

```
module type group = sig
  type t
  val (+): t -> t -> t
end
module Int: group = struct
  type t
  let (+) = (+)
end
```

the resulting module is unusable because there is no way to construct a value of type t exposed in the module type `group`.

Comment: A module that defines an abstract type must also provide some interface to get data into and out of that abstract type. For instance, `to_list` and `from_list` functions.

Comment: @octachron can you review here https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/284632/binary-tree-zipper-with-basic-operations ?